# Storage solutions for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, amazon-s3, storage

I am developing an application for iPhone that needs to be able to update data constantly, so we are doing this currently by requesting data from our server every time a page loads and that is all fine and good currently, since there is only one person (myself) pinging the our web server.

However, we want to move all of this to a third party server that is scalable and easy to access because we do not know the number of people in the end that will be using this application simultaneously.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a simple, cheap, and reliable storage solution, that we can simply access the contents of a file using HTTP GET requests.

I was looking into Amazon S3. Does anyone know if this is a good solution, or have examples of code they used to access this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to just go with Amazon S3 and it is working out great, and is super cheap to just store some files and access them publicly.

It is a great solution for anyone who needs a small server solution that will definitely not break the bank at all, and runs on something reliable.

I recommend it.